# How to reward sender when accept facebook invites on iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-invite

My client wants to make a small game for iOS and Android that rewards users when their friends accept their invites through Facebook.

I've read several questions and solutions I found on this site about getting the "from" and "to" fields from the facebook request.

However, on MOBILE, when a new user clicks a notification on FB apps, he/she will be redirected to the appstore page and need to download the app first.
So after downloading, when new user opens and logs in to the app, how can I know who is the sender so that I can reward him?

Comment: you cannot do that. the most you can do is check if the app install came from a facebook campaign, but this doesn't help with rewarding a particular user...

Comment: Thanks for the info, that's what I'm suspecting as well. 
But is there any official document saying that?
I need some evidence to tell my client

Comment: am I not official enough for you? ;) It seems I have to work on my reputation...

Comment: ;) you've got a lot of reputation here Michael. But of course if there is an official FB document to support this, it would be easier for me to tell my client ;)